# Which rpm i need to download for pcapplusplus library?

Tags: pcap, libpcap, pcapplusplus, pcap-ng

### getting error

fatal error: SystemUtils.h: No such file or directory
#include "SystemUtils.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Packet.h: No such file or directory
#include "Packet.h"
^~~~~~~~~~

---

these are the rpm installed on my setup:
libpcap-1.9.1-5.el8.x86_64
libpcap-devel-1.9.1-5.el8.x86_64

so i want to know which rpm should i download to use pcapplusplus library in my code?????

Comment: have you followed [this document](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/install)?

Comment: there is currently no rpm installation for PcapPlusPlus. You can download binaries from the latest release: https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/tag/v22.11
Or using one of the package manager described in: https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/install, or build the latest release from source